# Phong shading in OpenGL: line of light from the center of the world

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl

I implemented a Phong shader in GLSL, but there is a bug.

**What you are (supposed) to see down below:**

- A point light source rotating around the center of the world,

  - with a **radiance of (0, 100, 0)**
- A textured quad with **kd of (1, 0, 0)**.

**The problem is:**

- Why is there a a **green line to the center of the world** instead of a **green spot light where the quad is lit**? (where the center of the point light source is)

  - (Btw in this case there would be only a yellow spot of light, because red + green = yellow)

[image]

**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 ModelMatrix, ViewMatrix, ProjectionMatrix;   

uniform vec4 wLiPos[5];       // pos of light source 
uniform vec3 wEye;         // pos of eye
uniform int lightSize;      //number of lights

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vtxPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vtxNorm;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vtxUV;

out vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 wNormal;           // normal in world space
out vec3 wView[5];             // view in world space
out vec3 wLight[5];            // light dir in world space

void main() {
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(vtxPos, 1);
    texCoord = vtxUV;
    vec4 wPos = ModelMatrix * vec4(vtxPos, 1);
    wNormal = (vec4(vtxNorm, 0) * inverse(ModelMatrix)).xyz;
    for(int i = 0; i < lightSize; i++) {
        wView[i] = wEye * wPos.w - wPos.xyz;
        wLight[i] = wLiPos[i].xyz * wPos.w - wPos.xyz * wLiPos[i].w;
    }
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D samplerUnit;

uniform vec3 kd, ks, ka;   // diffuse, specular, ambient ref
uniform vec3 La, Le[5];    // ambient and point source rad
uniform float shininess;    // shininess for specular ref
uniform int lightSize;

in vec2 texCoord;    
in vec3 wNormal;       // interpolated world sp normal
in vec3 wView[5];         // interpolated world sp view
in vec3 wLight[5];        // interpolated world sp illum dir


layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main() {     
    vec3 color = vec3(0, 0, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < lightSize; i++) {
        vec3 N = normalize(wNormal);
        vec3 V = normalize(wView[i]);
        vec3 L = normalize(wLight[i]);
        vec3 H = normalize(L + V);
        float cost = max(dot(N,L), 0);
        float cosd = max(dot(N,H), 0);
        color += ka * La + (kd * cost + (ks * pow(cosd, shininess)) * Le[i]) / pow(length(wLight[i]), 2);
    }
    vec3 gamma = vec3(1.0/2.2);
    fragmentColor = vec4(pow(color * vec3(texture2D(samplerUnit, texCoord)), gamma), 1);
}
```

Comment: Also, why are multiplying the light position by the w component of the position?

Comment: I was about to comment the same thing. Division by W is typical for things that have had a perspective matrix performed on them. It should not be needed for the world positions of lights.

Comment: wLiPos is a vec4, and I have to avoid dividing by zero, so I cross multiplied in the formula.

Comment: Now I multiple by the transpose of the inverse of the modelMatrix, but nothing changed.
wNormal = (vec4(vtxNorm, 0) * transpose(inverse(ModelMatrix))).xyz;

Comment: You don't need the W component for world transformations. You can truncate the vec4*mat4 result to a vec3.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a typo. wLightPos is not in world, it's a vec4, so it can be in the infinity for example.

Comment: Or you mean that wPos? But if yes, then the w component is always 1, so that multiplication shouldn't change anything.

Comment: but if I just write eye - pos and LightPos - pos, everything stays the same.

Comment: How does it look if you remove the distance attenuation?  (*le[i] and / pow(length(wLight[i]), 2)  )

Comment: Didn't fix it. https://i.gyazo.com/814598d0d3afea8d9e83b6c4abb84854.png

Comment: If I comment out the kd part in the color: https://i.gyazo.com/0006479371f58a9931250b2d03dcd244.png
So the specular part causes it. With only ka and kd:
https://i.gyazo.com/e9630d77a2dc443aa17412a2d2cc486a.png

Comment: It's something about the 'cosd'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to set the **wEye uniform**, so it was always **(0, 0, 0)**.